# Setting the active link in a Twitter Bootstrap custom Navbar in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i'm working on wordpress with the-bootstrap theme (based on twitter bootstrap).the links in my navbar are working fine as dynamically but i have made the custom navbar and now my navbar links are not showing active states. how can i achieve it via jquery.

Here is the code for navbar:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

    <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>

    <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
    <!--<a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>-->

    <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
     <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">How It works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Investor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Entrepreneur</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
   alert('clicked');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: @foxygen: i have updated my question please check.

Comment: its the-bootstrap theme based on bootstrap 2.3

Comment: It seems to work already, http://jsfiddle.net/znt7v7f2/, is that not what you wanted?

Comment: @foxygen: somehow its not working for me..its shos the active box on links when clicked but but when the next page loaded its goes to firts link again.